# Solution to $f(x)=g(y)$

Tags: functions

Proof that this functional equation has the solution $f(x)=c$, $g(y)=c$.
If i plug $f(x)=x$ ,$g(y)=y$ that would also be a solution right?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: I need proof that $f(x)=c$,$g(y)=c$

Comment: What is the functional equation?

Comment: f(x)=g(y) is the functional equation,i have used wolfram to solve it but it does not give a proof

Comment: wolfram really gives that result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+f%28x%29%3Dg%28y%29 but the question is unclear

Comment: @AnatoliyR I need a proof to that solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $h(x,y)$ is some function such that $h(x,y)=f(x)=g(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.
Label the value $h(0,0)$ with the letter $c$. Then for an arbitrary point $(s,t),$ $$h(s,t)=f(s)=h(s,0)=g(0)=h(0,0)=c.$$

Comment: the statement h(x,y)=f(x)=g(y) is confusing

Comment: Alternately, I suppose you could just say that for all $x$, $f(x)=g(0)=f(0)$ and so it also follows $g(y)=f(x)=f(0).$ Unfortunately, I think this will be confusing either way.

Comment: I’d like to add a similar answer as a comment: I think one key idea is to fix a variable and let the other vary. If $x=x_0$ fixed, then $h(x_0,y)=f(x_0)= g(y)$ for all $y$. Now $f(x_0)$ is a constant and $g(y)$ is always equal to that constant for all $y$; hence $g$ has to be a constant function. Now, $f(x)=g(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, but $g$ was a constant identically, hence $f$ must be a constant too. And of course they should be the same constants. If we also know that these are differentiable, seeing them as functions of two variable, equating partials would also give the same result.